# IEnumerable extension method with String.Join returns System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable, extension-methods

I'm surprised that `list.Join()` returns `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    list.Add("1024");
    list.Add("2048");

    Console.WriteLine(list.Join());

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

with an extension method as

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", list);
    }
}
```

I don't understand it does not return what I'm expected, with the context of I *think* I'm so familiar with `string.join` and extension methods.

---

I was thinking internally it would be something like this

```
static string Join(IEnumerable list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        sb.Append(item).Append(", ");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

---

In the end, I use this version, to support generic and non-generic version.

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable list)
{
    return Join(list.Cast<object>());
}

public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return string.Join(",", list);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't bind to [this oveload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) because your IEnumerable isn't generic.

Comment: You're using `System.Collections.IEnumerable` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` on `Join` method inside `StringExtensions`. Change to `public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> list)` & both of them works.

Comment: Take in a generic `IEnumerable<>` **or**,  when you call `string.Join`, change the second argument to `list.Cast<object>()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is: the extension method casts the generic `List<string>`/`IEnumerable<string>` to a non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Because of that you this will call [this `params` overload of `string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) with a single object here:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable list)
{
    return string.Join(", ", list);
}
```

Since the object is a `List<string>` which doesn't override `ToString` you will get the type-name as result: `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`

You could change your extension method in the following way:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable list)
{
    return string.Join(", ", list.Cast<object>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! how about `public static string Join(this IEnumerable<object> list)`?

Comment: What would be the benefit of this extension? You can already call string.join with this directly

Comment: yes, to call this `String.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)`, and use `string.join` directly without `cast<>`.

Comment: But you can already do this. So no need to provide another extension that does what is already possible. Your extension makes sense to provide it also for non generic sequences

Comment: I would still prefer `public static string Join<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list)
    {
      return string.Join(", ", list);
    }` even if it gives you the same functionality. It feels ugly to use the old non-generic collection types. Also, there is a reason why the authors of `string.Join` did not include support for the old types: The new types are nicer. With my method, it is nice to know that if you join a type-safe collection of value types, such as `List<int>`, you do not box all the items when you create your string. Your method does the boxing.

Comment: I guess Tim's point is the interface/contract is here, and with many dependencies potentially, in order not to break the code, then use the cast way. else the generic one will be better.

Comment: @Timeless If you use types that are `IEnumerable` without being `IEnumerable<>`, I suggest you include both overloads of your extension method.

Comment: To me, the benefit of the extension method here is that it allows the syntax `source.Where(x => something).Select(x => whatever).Where(x => foobar).Join()` which is more natural when read from left to right than the syntax `string.Join(", ", source.Where(x => something).Select(x => whatever).Where(x => foobar))`.

Comment: Double checked why did I make this extension method because `SqlException` error list inherits from non-generic `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Timeless: what `SqlException` error list? If you create a method that takes a `IEnumerable<T>` then you can't use it with non generic arguments. Your `IEnumerable` was fine

Comment: This `public sealed class SqlException : DbException`, `public SqlErrorCollection Errors { get; }`, and `SqlErrorCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable`

Comment: @Timeless: yes, and because it is not implementing `IEnumerable<SqlError>` your extension method won't be called and is completely useless. It's useless anyway because even if you pass a generic enumerable you could call [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) directly, there is already an overload since .NET 4. But my approach which accepts `IEnumerable` works with generic and non-generic sequences(because [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) inherits from `IEnumerable`).